# Git merge with remote branch issue

Tags: git

I am trying to merge my local repo with remote repo branch.

What I did --

```
> git status
On branch dev
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/dev'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    api.zip
        modified:   models/event.js

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Then I did,

```
> git pull origin dev

 * branch            dev -> FETCH_HEAD
   19d5d3e..86e0adc  dev -> origin/dev
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        models/event.js
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
Updating 19d5d3e..86e0adc
```

Then I did

```
> git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on dev: 19d5d3e Add banner text

> git pull origin dev
 * branch            dev -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating 19d5d3e..86e0adc
Fast-forward
 models/event.js | 6166 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++---------------------------
 1 file changed, 3084 insertions(+), 3082 deletions(-)

> git stash pop
Auto-merging models/event.js
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in models/event.js
Removing api.zip


>git status
On branch dev
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/dev'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    api.zip

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both modified:   models/event.js


>git stash apply --index
models/event.js: needs merge
unable to refresh index
```

How can I merge? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a conflict in `models/event.js`. You should resolve it manually and then `git add models/event.js`.

Answer (score 0):

First, examine your stash to verify that it contains only changes made to event.js
Then try this

```
git reset --hard origin/dev
git stash pop
```

Then resolve any merge conflicts.